# Django ManyToMany intermediary model, move relationship

Tags: django, django-models, django-related-manager

So, after reading the documentation regarding intermediary model's, it seems that there's no built-in way of changing one side of a relationship without clearing all relationships with that side.

But how can I do this anyway? I was thinking that I may have to store all of the relationships in an array / object so I can recreate them when needing to change 1 or more relations.

My Models:

```
Company
Camera
CompanyCameraRelationship
```

I would want to change the relationship between `Company 1` and `Camera 1` to `Company 1` and `Camera 2`. So in order to do this, I must clear **all** relationships between `Company 1` and other Cameras?

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean you want to change the existing intermediary objects? You can update them using the intermediary model.

```
CompanyCameraRelationship.objects.filter(company='Company 1', camera='Camera 1').update(camera='Camera 2')
```

Comment: WHAT!? You're kidding me ... why isn't this at all mentioned in the documentation? And if it is, can you point it out to me?

Comment: @dcolumbus You can work with the through model like any other model. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships Describes how the through models can be used.

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you very much.